# Are headphones with EMF measurement of 10,000 milligauss harmful to me?

Tags: rf, radio, headphones, radiation, emf

I used a [EMF detector app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mreprogramming.ultimateemfdetector) on my phone and measured the EMF output on my wired headphones. It measured around 10,000 milligauss on one part of both ear cups. Since wearing these headphones on my head for long periods of time, will this cause injury to my head or immune system?

Comment: No need to be hostile over such trivial stuff. Yes, trivial. 10,000 milligauss is equal to 10 gauss. The Earths magnetic field is 500 milligauss, or 0.5 gauss. 10,000 gauss equals 1 Tesla, a fairly strong magnetic field. The LHC collider in France/Switzerland has a field strength of 8 Teslas, enough to bend steel beams. 10,000 milligauss maybe legit, but it is pathetically weak overall.

Comment: @Sparky256 Source?

Comment: @Sparky256 I meant the source for 10,000 milligauss being "pathetically" weak.

Comment: That was a comment on the relatively vast difference between local magnetic fields, including Earths, and specialised high intensity fields, including MRI machines. None of which cause harm to humans or animals. USF had a mouse 'floating' in an intense magnetic field only to prove it could cancel out gravity if strong enough. My comment was not meant to be an insult or snide remark.

Answer (score 4):

The ability to measure something, with your phone app for instance, makes it far easier to worry about it.

Consider the mass experiment that is being done now, has been ongoing for the past few decades, of people all over the world (billions?) wearing headphones. They will have similar exposure to low value DC magnetic fields. There is another population, running into millions, of people who've had exposure to fields 1000s times more powerful, inside MRI scanners.

With all that exposure, you might expect that any harmful effects would have shown up by now, and they haven't. Which sits fairly nicely with there being no known way that magnetic fields can harm you. Interestingly, there *are* known ways that ionising radiation like X-rays can harm you, and precautions are taken to minimise exposure to both to patients and staff  in medical facilities. Contrast the two approaches taken to magnetism and X-rays.

Unfortunately, me knowing that magnetic fields are harmless doesn't make it any easier for you to feel comfortable wearing headphones, now that you can put a number on the leakage field from the ear cups. It depends whether you're into conspiracy theories whether you'll ever accept reassurances from any source.

Full disclosure, I once worked on MRI machines, and was often bunged into the machine when we needed a test image. When the ladies in the lab were running the test, a man was sent it, and vice versa, and the image was always of the genital region. Oh how we laughed! For all that strong magnetic fields are difficult to work with (wipe credit cards, zap pacemakers, get fork-lift trucks stuck to the magnet (yup, done that), bend CRT traces off the screen, send steel wrenches flying through the air), damaging human tissue through direct action is not one of the problems.

Comment: What about 12 hours a day exposure to the magnetic field? That's far more exposure than what you described in your answer.